# como puedo solucionar este error en php con laravel de array

Tags: php, laravel, array

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::create(): Argument #1 ($attributes) must be of type array, App\Models\DetalleCompras given, called in C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\GitHub\AIF_Dimotos_\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany.php on line 364

este es el error que me esta mostrando para para mostrar, estoy tratando de realizar un modulo de compras y no me esta guardando los datos en la base de datos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [este es el array que tengo pero no me esta guardando nada en la base de datos, ninguno de los campos que estoy llamando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/593734/este-es-el-array-que-tengo-pero-no-me-esta-guardando-nada-en-la-base-de-datos-n)

Answer (score 0):

El error indica que estás pasando una instancia de App\Models\DetalleCompras como argumento en lugar de un array en el método create() de la relación HasOneOrMany, La función create() espera recibir un array de atributos para crear un nuevo modelo asociado a la relación. Asegúrate de pasar un array de atributos en lugar de una instancia del modelo.

```
$compra->detalleCompras()->create([
'campo1' => 'valor1',
'campo2' => 'valor2',
// Otros atributos
```

]);

Comment: gracias, pero estoy trayendo el array de la siguiente forma 

$idCompra  = $compras->id;

        
        $compras = Compra::create();

        foreach ($request->ID_Repuesto as $key => $repuestos) {
            $results[] = new DetalleCompras([
                "Precio" => $request->Precio[$key],
                "Cantidad" => $request->Cantidad[$key],
                "ID_Repuesto" => $request->ID_Repuesto[$key],
                "ID_Compra" => $idCompra
            ]);
        }

        $compras->detallecompras()->createMany($results);

        return redirect('/compras');

Comment: Si justamente ahi `new DetalleCompras(["Precio" => $request->Precio[$key], "Cantidad" => $request->Cantidad[$key], "ID_Repuesto" => $request->ID_Repuesto[$key], "ID_Compra" => $idCompra])` estas creando una instancia de DetalleCompras entonces $result de un array de instancias de DetalleCompras, por tal motivo te lanza la excepción en al crear en la linea `$compras->detallecompras()->createMany($results);`, quitale el new DetalleCompras y que solo sea un array asociativo

Comment: Quedaria de esta forma `$idCompra = $compras->id;
$compras = Compra::create();
foreach ($request->ID_Repuesto as $key => $repuestos) {
    $results[] = ["Precio" => $request->Precio[$key], "Cantidad" => $request->Cantidad[$key], "ID_Repuesto" => $request->ID_Repuesto[$key], "ID_Compra" => $idCompra];
}
$compras->detallecompras()->createMany($results);
return redirect('/compras');`  ahi ya no deberia darte problemas

Comment: buenas tardes me gustaria contactarme con usted ya que solo soy un estudiante y soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y no entiendo muy bien, me disculpo con usted ya que no se que tendría que quitar en el controlador y quisiera que usted me ayudara para poder terminar este trabajo ya que es un trabajo final
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'Precio' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `compras` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2023-05-15 22:09:03, 2023-05-15 22:09:03))
y me salio ya este nuevo error

Comment: Escribime a https://www.facebook.com/McAlvaroDev,  si puedo ayudarte con algo con gusto

Comment: buenos dias ya te escribí por el link que me compartiste

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146049/discussion-between-danny-suarez-and-mc-alvaro).