# este es el array que tengo pero no me esta guardando nada en la base de datos, ninguno de los campos que estoy llamando

Tags: php, laravel, array

este es el codigo en el que estoy trayendo el array

```
    $compras = Compra::create();


    foreach ($request->ID_Repuesto as $key => $repuestos) {
        $results[] = new DetalleCompras([
            "Precio" => $request->Precio[$key],
            "Cantidad" => $request->Cantidad[$key],
            "ID_Repuesto" => $request->ID_Repuesto[$key],
            "ID_Compra" => $idCompra
        ]);
    }


    $compras->detallecompras()->createMany($results);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la tabla de mi base de datos donde estoy tratando de que guarde los datos pero no me les deja guardar muestra que se guarda pero no se guarda al parecer jajaja

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el error que muestra en laravel cuando trato de guardar los datos en el formulario de crear un compra

y este es el error que me muestra

Comment: El uso de `createMany` esta explicado en la [documentacion](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)."

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
$compras = Compra::create();
foreach ($request->ID_Repuesto as $key => $repuestos) {
    $results[] = ["Precio" => $request->Precio[$key], "Cantidad" => $request->Cantidad[$key], "ID_Repuesto" => $request->ID_Repuesto[$key], "ID_Compra" => $idCompra];
}
$compras->detallecompras()->createMany($results);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución. Sería bueno que añadas más información o una explicación breve respecto a tu solución.

Comment: Las respuestas que tienen solo código tienden a considerarse de mala calidad. Es mejor si añades una explicación, aunque sea breve, de cómo o por qué el código resuelve el problema planteado, o de cuál era en realidad ese problema. Para más información lee [answer].

Comment: estoy abierto a otras respuestas pero me sigue apareciendo otro error  @Cris223511.dev